# How to autoplay Google native ads without having to click play button and remove default controls in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, native-ads

I have implemented native ads in my app on recylerview playing videos automatically. I need video ads to autoplay so as to blend with the experience of my app and I want to remove the default play pause and mute button from the native ads video. I have tried to use **videocontroller.play()** after populating adview but didn't work. I have also tried **setCustomControlsRequested(true)** in my video ads options but the same controls are still there. Please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you solve it?